# Atualização em tempo real firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

Tenho um método que quero que verifique a todo momento no banco de dados se um campo do nó filho é modificado(no caso, o campo "status"), quando ele é alterado, quero que o texto na tela do android seja modificado. Estou conseguindo fazer a alteração no texto, porém quando saio e entro na tela de novo a mensagem some (mesmo quando o status no banco de dados é alterado). Código:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

    circleImageViewUser = findViewById(R.id.circleImageViewUser);
    txtOcorrencias = findViewById(R.id.txtOcorrencias);
    txtStatus = findViewById(R.id.txtStatus);
    txtPendencias = findViewById(R.id.txtPendencias);
    txtSaudacao = findViewById(R.id.txtSaudacao);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbarPrincipal);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    recuperarUsuario();
    recuperarFotoUsuario();

    verificaStatusOcorrencia();

}


public void verificaStatusOcorrencia() {
    String idUsuario = UserFirebase.getDadosUsuarioLogado().getIdUsuario();
    usuarioRef = firebaseRef.child("ocorrencias").child(idUsuario);

    usuarioRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Ocorrencia ocorrencia = snapshot.getValue(Ocorrencia.class);

                if (ocorrencia.getStatus() == "1") {
                    txtStatus.setText(Ocorrencia.A_CAMINHO);
                    txtStatus.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                    txtStatus.setTextSize(16);
                } else if (ocorrencia.getStatus() == "0") {
                    txtStatus.setText(Ocorrencia.AGUARDANDO);
                    txtStatus.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    txtStatus.setTextSize(16);
                } else if (ocorrencia.getStatus() == "2"){
                    txtStatus.setText(Ocorrencia.OK);
                    txtStatus.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                    txtStatus.setTextSize(17);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Banco de dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seu codigo irá mostrar sempre o status da ultima ocorrencia deste usuário (não necessáriamente a ultima cadastrada, mas sim a ultima no final do foreach pois não estas usando nenhum ordenamento). Se quiser mostrar o status de uma ocorrencia específica, deves adicionar o id da ocorrencia na referencia e remover o foreach do codigo. Também podes definir qual ocorrencia desejas verificar dentro do foreach.